# Как вынести контроллеры в отдельные сборки?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть у меня веб-приложение, в котором соединено два очень разнородных api, скажем:

```
[Route("api1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "foo value1", "foo value2" };
    }
}
```

и

```
[Route("api2/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BarController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "bar value1", "bar value2" };
    }
}
```

И хочу я вынести контроллеры по разным сборкам, что-то типа:

[image: solution structure]

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47617994/5752652

Answer (score 7):

Нашёл ответ на английском so:

[How to use a controller in another assembly in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47617994/5752652)

Для asp.net core 2.x:

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
```

Для 3.x:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assembly = typeof(**AnyTypeFromRequiredAssembly**).Assembly;

    services.AddControllers()
        .PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
}
```

(в комментариях пишут, что и старые методы пока работают)

Итого, в моём примере:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Application1.Controllers.FooController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Application2.Controllers.BarController).Assembly)
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Документация по теме:

- [Share controllers, views, Razor Pages and more with Application Parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.1)