# Один проект является поддоменом другим?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

MVC CORE 2.1; У меня есть два проекта Web ( основной проект, в нём есть форум, блог.. ) и Game - так скажем игровой проект, можно ли сделать так, что бы проект Game был поддоменом проекта Web, т.е если у Web ссылка localhost:4325 к примеру, то тогда бы Game работал по аддресу game.localhost:4325

Comment: Настройка роутов веб сервера (например ваши сервера крутятся на `192.168.0.100:5555` и `192.168.0.100:6666`. И если вы вводите `192.168.0.100:80/Game` вас кидает на `192.168.0.100:5555`, а если введете `192.168.0.100:80/Web` - вас кинет на `192.168.0.100:6666`).

Comment: А как это сделать в рамках mvc core?

Comment: Это не относится к mvc core, это вопрос настройки окружения. Домен вам определяет веб-сервер, если вы не про localhost говорите, а про реальное развёртывание  -- то это не kestrel будет (вендор не рекомендует ставить его в прод), а nginx или IIS. Также возможно вам будет полезен вот такой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1062516/213987

Comment: @JigglyDezar я думаю в проекте можно сделать так: у вас есть один слой `API`, вы разделяете Логический слой `Game` и `Web` (и соответственно у вс получается несколько разные контроллеры `api`... ну и дальше роутами решаете свои проблемы (т е по факту я предложил слияние 2х проектов)